# Patched fonts not showing up on gnome-terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, fonts, gnome

I installed the patched font "Source Code Pro" from https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts#option-3-install-script on my Ubuntu 18.10 box.

I can see the font showing up on the Fonts program (as SauceCodePro).

I want to set it as the font for GNOME Terminal app (Edit -> Preferences -> Custom Font), however this font doesn't show up.

I have tried running `sudo fc-cache -fv ~/.local/share/fonts`, as well as restarting my computer. I also tried reinstalling the `gnome-terminal` package, but no dice.

Does anyone have any suggestion for what I could do here?

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046871/nerd-font-not-fond-in-terminal-profile/1046966.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks to @egmont's link to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046871/nerd-font-not-fond-in-terminal-profile/, I figured out a way to get around this, as mentioned in one of the comments in that post:

- Install GNOME Tweaks
- Set the system monospace font to "SauceCodePro Mono Regular"
- In the Terminal's Font Preference, I leave the Custom Font option *unchecked*, .i.e use system font.

Comment: Using Tweaks was what finally solved this for me. Thank you!

Comment: Find GNOME TWEAKS HERE: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-linux
Find ProFontIIx here: https://tobiasjung.name/downloadfile.php?file=profontiix.zip
Install it, and set it to your system monospace font at 9pt.
Thank you, and you're welcome.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1871807) with gnome-terminal.

A workaround is to set the font of a gnome-terminal profile by using dconf.

First you will need to find out the id of your profile:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

This will output information for all your profiles.
Grab the id of the profile you want to set the font for, it should look something like `:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9` and then set the font for that terminal by running:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/font  "'<chosen_font_name> <font_size>'"
```

**The double quoting is important, I don't know why but you need to doubly quote your font and size.**

So for example I used this to set a font I patched with nerd fonts with a size of 13, and the command was:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/font  "'UbuntuMono Nerd Font Mono 13'"
```

**Note `use-system-font` should be false, you can set this by ticking 'Custom font' in the profile options dialog or set it via dconf.**

Comment: Thank you. I switched from Qt to Kitty. Now symbols in LunarVim are displayed correctly.